Connect Openstack to Keycloak
I have set up OpenStack using Kolla and now need to connect the Horizon dashboard to Keycloak using OpenID. The OpenStack documentation does not provide clear guidance on this. If anyone has experience with this setup, I would greatly appreciate your assistance.
I used the following methods but it doesn't guide me well.
https://docs.openstack.org/kolla-ansible/latest/contributor/setup-identity-provider.html#configuring-kolla-ansible-to-use-the-identity-provider
https://wiki.teria.org/howto/index.php?title=Keystone_with_OpenID_Connect
